# CS1061: demo_aspx does not contain a definition for rdMale_CheckedChanged and no extension method rdMale_CheckedChanged accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and following a books example and failing on the first example.

When I compile the example I receive:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'demo_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'rdMale_CheckedChanged' and no extension method 'rdMale_CheckedChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'demo_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 23:         
Line 24:         
Line 25:         
Line 26:         
Line 27:

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DemoApplication
{
    public partial class Demo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Name"] = txtName.Text;
            Response.Write(Session["Name"]);

            lblName.Visible = false;
            txtName.Visible = false;
            lstLocation.Visible = false;
            chkC.Visible = false;
            chkASP.Visible = false;
            rdMale.Visible = false;
            rdFemale.Visible = false;
            btnSubmit.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

has anyone any ideas please?

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. is this all c# code? Check the xaml designer page that select bdMale checkBox and in the right property section, at the topright, there's thunder picture. press it and check if the checkedchanged is activated or not.

Comment: Hi Kay Lee. Thanks for your suggestions. I removed this line of code from the web page and it works? Checked="True" OnCheckedChanged="rdMale_CheckedChanged"

Comment: Hi, Strutter, any result?

Comment: Hi Kay.Yes all is fine now. Thanks for your help.